# Shouldn't the usernames on a historically locked question update as well?

Tags: discussion, bug, locked-questions, historical-lock

I came across a historically locked question about an earlier Winter Bash and saw this:

[image]

However, Abby T. Miller and abby hairboat are the same person! Why didn't the user name update? I think it is because it was a historically locked question, but not allowing the usernames to change, seems like a thing that goes to far – what if an owner of a historically locked answer wants to have its account deleted? Will that answer show his username and avatar visible?

Comment: Heraclitus tells us that we never step in the same river twice. Who can say how many rivers this hairboat sailed in a month's time?

Comment: @Shog9 you are sharper than usual today. Is this the Winter Spirit?

Comment: I'm trying to shake a cold; let's just leave it at "some manner of spirit".